# Using bind9 forwarding to openvpn does not work

Tags: openvpn, bind

i have an openvpn running on my server. It works, and when i check with traceroute, i see that the first ip address is 10.12.4.1, so i think my vpn?

Heres my openvpn conf from my ubuntu server

```
client
remote XXXXXXXXXXXX 443
dev tun
proto udp
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/user.txt

#redirect-gateway def1
route-nopull
route 0.0.0.0 128.0.0.0 net_gateway
route 128.0.0.0 128.0.0.0 net_gateway
route XXX.xx.xXx.xx 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway
route XXX.xx.xXx.xx 255.255.255.255 vpn_gateway

dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8

resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-disable
auth SHA256
ping 5
ping-exit 60
ping-timer-rem
explicit-exit-notify 2
script-security 2
remote-cert-tls server
route-delay 5
verb 4
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

up /etc/openvpn/update_bind_forwarder.sh

ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key
```

I will just run two ip addresses to my vpn_gateway. Everything else can go direct.
So if i ping these two ips, i get 10.12.4.1 in traceroute. For everything else, i get my own server ip. So it works?

But the problem is, when i will use my openvpn as forwarders in bind9, i didnt get anything and cant use my server as DNS Server.

Here is my named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;
    allow-query { any; 10.12.4.216; 192.168.0.0/32; 127.0.0.1; };
    forwarders {
        10.12.4.216;
    };
    forward only;
};
```

If i put 8.8.8.8 into the forwarders, it works!
So i think t here is a problem with my vpn server!
The options are generated from openvpn protocol, cause the ip changes everytime.
The 10.12.4.216 in that example comes from `ip addr show tun0`

What i see also when grep named from log

```
named[5621]: managed-keys-zone: Unable to fetch DNSKEY set '.': timed out
```

Only when i use my vpn server... but why?!
Didnt find a way online, how to fix that

Did someone have an idea, why bind9 doesnt work in my case with openvpn?

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve here? What is 10.12.4.216? Why do you want to use that to resolve names? Where is BIND running? How is your network configured?

Comment: It is one server. 10.12.4.216 is my openvpn on the same server. I want to use my server as an DNS for my router. So Linux Server with bind9 as DNS Server but with my openvpn behind it. But doesnt get it running with openvpn in bind9

Comment: Is your router connecting to the server via OpenVPN? Your setup really makes no sense to me, and you don't explain it in enough detail. Furthermore it feels very much like a home user question...

Comment: I just want to use my ubuntu server as DNS Server on my router at home. And on the ubuntu is running openvpn. Thats all. Just want to use my ubuntu as my own DNS with openvpn on it

Comment: Home questions are off topic on Serverfault.

Comment: The dns server is also than for people with the same problem. So not only at home